# Removing rows from R data frame when a column value exists in more than one row

Tags: r

I’m new to R and making pretty good progress but I’m having a little trouble with the following problem.

I merged multiple data frames.
I want to remove rows based on the values of ONE column of data. That is, the entire row need not be identical to another row (although it may be) in order for it to be removed.

In terms of pseudo code,
If column “x” of row i = column “x” of row j, remove either row i or row j but not both.
If column “x” of row i = column “x” of row j = column “x” of row k, remove two of the rows but not all three.

An example might be that I have several lists of employees, some from years ago and others more recent. Each employee has a unique identifier (e.g., their SSN) stored in column “x” but the rest of the data may or may not be the same (e.g., new address, new last name due to marriage, etc.). I want just one row of data for each employee/former employee.

How can I do this if I pre-sort the data frame on column “x” values in an ascending order?
How can I do this if I do not sort the data frame at all?

Comment: See `?duplicated`. Sounds like you want `df[!duplicated(df$x), ]`, sorting doesn't matter.

Comment: Awesome user name by the way

Comment: sorting kind of matters, in that it is the first of each `df$x` which will be kept.